# Ansible: How to suppress SIGHUP

Tags: ssh, signals, ansible, nohup

Ansible seems to be sending SIGHUP signals at the end of (certain?) tasks. This is a problem as the tasks call a bash script which in turn starts a server instance.

Now if the closing of Ansibles SSH session sends a SIGHUP, this will actually shutdown the server - the start of which was the key point of the Ansible task in the first place.

**So, is there a way I can guarantee that Ansible will use SSH in a way that will *not* send a SIGHUP signal when closing the task/session?**

I could theoretically start the bashscript using `nohup`. But this seems to be just a dirty workaround, as I know that SSH is capable of doing what I want: if I manually compose and pass the script command via SSH as such:

```
ssh user@server "scriptToStartMyServer.sh params"
```

.. then it works fine and no SIGHUP is sent (thus the server survives and is not shutdown immediately after being started).

---

*Edit:*
*Sadly we cannot avoid using these bash scripts to start servers and we cannot really change them as this is something given to us by the customer.*

Comment: Perhaps a related question would be is it appropriate for your _service_ to behave like that on SIGHUP? According to signal(7) the SIGHUP signal is sent to a process when its controlling terminal is closed. In modern systems, this signal usually means that the controlling pseudo or virtual terminal has been closed. This is exactly what's happening when Ansible disconnects. I could understand if some services would reload their config, but a non-interactive service should not terminate on SIGHUP...

Comment: Sadly I can't change the behavior of the script (which sadly does not act the way a service should) as they (and the libraries used therein) are provided by the customer. :(